# AWK end of line sign in regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have a simple awk script named "script.awk" that contains:

```
/\/some_simple_string/ { print $0;}
```

I'm using it to parse some file that contains:
(by using: cat file | awk -f script.awk)

```
14 catcat one_two/some_thing
15 catcat one_three/one_more_some_simple_string
16 dogdog one_two/some_simple_string_again
17 dogdog one_four/some_simple_string
18 qweqwe firefire/ppp
```

I want the script to only print the stroke that fully reflect "/some_simple_string[END_OF_LINE]" but not 2 or 3.
Is there any simple way to do it?

I think, the most appropriate way is to add end-of-line sigh to the regular expression.
So it will parse only strokes that starting with "/some.." and have a new line at the end of "..string[END_OF_LINE]"

Desired output:

```
17 dogdog one_four/some_simple_string
```

Sorry for confusion, I was asking for END OF LINE sign in regular expressions.
The correct answer is:

```
/\/some_simple_string$/ { print $0;}
```

Comment: What do you call a row? In that case what is the desired output ?

Comment: That was very confusing with the original formulation of the question, sorry.

Comment: Basically my fault, poor description, sorry for that.

Comment: In that case you don't need `awk` at all just `grep '/some_simple_string$'`

Comment: Actually, the original issue was a bit more than that (I've just tried to simplify it). Basically, I wanted to print next string after the expression matched, so I'm using: { getline; print "something=" $0;}

Comment: @MikhailKalashnikov you really should have given all the information at the start clearly.. You don't want to do that, I have added the correct way to that using `awk`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use:

```
/\/some_simple_string$/ { print $0 }
```

I.e. match not only "some_simple_string" but match "/some_simple_string" followed by the end of the line ($ is end of line in regex)

Comment: That is probably what I've been looking for. I used to use: \\<some_simple_string\>\, but unfortunately it works only in gawk but not in awk.

Comment: @MikhailKalashnikov this answer won't print the last match only, I thought that is what you wanted? Also this will work with any POSIX compliant `awk` not just `gawk`.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work in awk v1.6, and I wanted it to be as portable as possible.

Comment: Warning: If your file has Windows line endings (`\r\n`), this might not work as expected. I suggest adding a `\s*` or similar (it depends on your dataset of course) to the end before the `$`.

Answer (score 3):

`grep '\some_simple_string$' file | tail -n 1` should do the trick.

Or if you really want to use `awk` do `awk '/\/some_simple_string/{x = $0}END{print x}'`

Comment: Both of these just print the last line the file not the last line matching the regular expression

Answer (score 3):

To return just the *last* of a group of matches, ...

Store the line in a variable and print it in the `END` block.

```
/some_simple_string/ { x = $0 }
END{ print x }
```

Comment: why not `END{print}` using the fact that `$0` is set at each line and that print implicitly prints `$0`?

Comment: I forgot about that. Haven't really used awk in a while. :)

Comment: `END {print}` is NOT a good solution.  It will print any last line, why do the search then??  File may contain other string at last line than `some_simple_string`. Do use `END{ print x }`

Comment: @luserdroog it seems this is not what the OP wants after all.

Answer (score 1):

To print all the matches that end with the string `/some_simple_string` using regular expression you need to anchor to the the end of the line using `$`. The most suitable tool for this job is `grep`:

```
$ grep '/some_simple_string$' file
```

In `awk` the command is much the same:

```
$ awk '/[/]some_simple_string$/' file
```

To print all lines after the matching you would do:

```
$ awk 'print_flag{print;f=0} /[/]some_simple_string$/{print_flag=1}' file
```

Or just combine `grep` and `tail` if it makes it clearer using context option `-A` to print the following lines:

```
$ grep -A1 '/some_simple_string$' file | tail -n 1
```

Comment: What is `print_flag`? Is that an awk command or something you invented?

Comment: Just a variable name I choose.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes find that the input records can have a trailing carriage return (\r).
Yes, I deal with both Windows and Linux text files.
So I add the following 'pre-processor' to my awk scripts:

```
1 == 1 { # preprocess all records
  res = gsub("\r", "") # remove unwanted trailing char
  if(res>0 && NR<100) { print "(removed stuff)" > "/dev/stderr" } # optional
}
```

Answer (score 0):

more optimally, let `FS` do the work instead of having it perform unnecessary and unrelated field splitting (adding the `\r` bit for `Windows/DOS` completeness):

> ```
> mawk '!_<NF' FS='[/]some_simple_string[\r]?$'
> ```

```
17 dogdog one_four/some_simple_string
```